# Current Population Survey (CPS) Data in Bertrand/Duflo/Mullainathan

Tags: dataset, stata, difference-in-difference

I am trying to replicate the results in [Bertrand, M., Duflo, E., Mullainathan, S., 2004. How Much Should We Trust Differences-In-Differences Estimates? The Quarterly Journal of Economics 119 (1). 249–275.](http://qje.oxfordjournals.org/content/119/1/249.abstract) On page 255 the authors state that

> "We extract data on women in their fourth interview month in
>   the Merged Outgoing Rotation Group of the CPS for the years
>   1979 to 1999. We focus on all women between the ages 25 and 50.
>   We extract information on weekly earnings, employment status,
>   education, age, and state of residence. The sample contains
>   nearly 900,000 observations."

However, when I download the data and follow their conditions than I only obtain some 145,000 observations instead of 900,000. My Stata-code is as follows:

```
use "http://www.nber.org/morg/annual/morg79.dta", clear
forvalues i=80/99 {
    display `i'
    quietly append using "http://www.nber.org/morg/annual/morg`i'.dta"
}

//We extract data on women in their fourth interview month in
//the Merged Outgoing Rotation Group of the CPS
keep if sex == 2 & intmonth == 4

//We focus on all women between the ages 25 and 50.
keep if age > 24 & age < 51 

//We extract information on weekly earnings, employment status,
//education, age, and state of residence.
keep age uearnwk state esr grade92

describe
```

Does anyone have an idea what's wrong here? I am thankful for any advise.

Comment: I think you want `keep if sex == 2 & minsamp == 4`. The `count` would be 876880.

Comment: No chance I could have found this on my own. Thanks, Roberto.

Comment: You also might want to consider something like looping over use age uearnwk state esr grade* sex intmonth age if inrange(age,25,50) & sex==2 & minsamp==4 using "http://www.nber.org/morg/annual/morg`i'.dta", clear