# How to identify studies that should be replicated?

Tags: econometrics, finance, replicability

[In psychology voting on which studies should be replicated is established on a website](http://psychfiledrawer.org/top-20/). The [ReplicationWiki](http://replication.uni-goettingen.de) (that I founded) [offers a voting option](http://replication.uni-goettingen.de/wiki/index.php/Help:Replication_relevance_ranking) for studies in economics and related fields, but it is not yet used much. I already saw a couple of questions on specific papers here ([a](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/142511/svar-with-taylor-rule), [b](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/52527/unable-to-fit-negative-binomial-regression-in-r-attempting-to-replicate-publish), [c](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/95243/current-population-survey-cps-data-in-bertrand-duflo-mullainathan)), [in the quantitative finance stack](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/706/how-do-i-reproduce-the-cross-sectional-regression-in-intraday-patterns-in-the-c), and [in the academia stack](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/1401/how-to-get-the-data-to-reproduce-a-published-result/1402) and added the studies to the wiki and a link to questions here ([a1](http://replication.uni-goettingen.de/wiki/index.php/Vector_Autoregressions_(JEP_2001)), [b1](http://replication.uni-goettingen.de/wiki/index.php/Talk:Innovation_and_Institutional_Ownership_(AER_2013)), [c1](http://replication.uni-goettingen.de/wiki/index.php/How_Much_Should_We_Trust_Differences-In-Differences_Estimates), [quant](http://replication.uni-goettingen.de/wiki/index.php/Intraday_Patterns_in_the_Cross-section_of_Stock_Returns_(JF_2010)), academia [1](http://replication.uni-goettingen.de/wiki/index.php/Do_conditional_cash_transfers_influence_migration%3F_A_study_using_experimental_data_from_the_Mexican_progresa_program_%28Demography_2005%29), [2](http://replication.uni-goettingen.de/wiki/index.php/Tax_Incentives_and_the_Decision_to_Purchase_Health_Insurance:_Evidence_from_the_Self-Employed_%28QJE_1994%29), [3](http://replication.uni-goettingen.de/wiki/index.php/Children_and_Their_Parents%27_Labor_Supply:_Evidence_from_Exogenous_Variation_in_Family_Size_%28AER_1998%29)).

There are many other places where such questions on replication of specific studies can be found, e.g., in the forums for specialized software ([d](http://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1305520-xtabond2-replication-exercise-what-am-i-doing-wrong)). To get further suggestions I would like to know if you have already replicated studies yourself or with your students. What would you think would be a mechanism that motivates to share such experience and help to identify the studies that should be replicated? And the replications that are already available somewhere but not yet listed in the wiki? Where would be the right place to ask?

Answer (score 3):

I would say that should be replicated studies are ones with important, counterintuitive, too good to be true or otherwise fishi results.

Replications are not being done because there is no fame in it, they are harder to publish and it's harder to get money for it, because of the perceived lack of originality and added value. If you can't get your replication published, you will not bother, therefore I think that mechanism would have to be on the side of scientific publishing.

You might want to look at many lab replication project https://osf.io/wx7ck/wiki/home/

Maybe academia se is better place to ask?

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the academia stack, I already found [further questions on specific studies there](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/1401/how-to-get-the-data-to-reproduce-a-published-result/1402) and will ask my question there, too. For the many labs replication project as far as I can see it was just a group of researchers who planned the project who chose which studies should be replicated, no open mechanism.